# Two Controls Reference One-Another Correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, circular-dependency

I have a ComboBox and a DateTimePicker control in a .net forms application.  The desired functionality for the relationship of the two controls is that a modification to one will change the value in the other.  Logic to modify the other control is in each controls change event; ComboBox "SelectedIndexChanged" and DateTimePicker "Changed" and it looks something like the following:

```
othercontrol.value = value;
```

Is there a clear way I can isolate change events from the respective controls to determine whether they were sent by the UI vs. the other control's change event to head off the loop the current setup will cause?

As I write this I realize I could probably change the other controls value by invoking the change event and passing some variation in the arguments from the corresponding change event instead of simply setting the other control's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the control's eventhandler before settings it's value and add it back immediately after setting the value.

```
othercontrol.SelectedChanged -= othercontrol_SelectedChanged;
othercontrol.value = value;
othercontrol.SelectedChanged += othercontrol_SelectedChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this then.

Ok, it's a bit hacky but this would work:

```
private bool eventBubbledDate = false;
private bool eventBubbleCombi = false;

protected override MyCombi_OnChange(object sender, eventargs e)
{
  if (eventBubbledDate)
  {
    eventBubbledDate = false;
    return;
  }
  eventBubbleCombi = true;
  myDateTime.Value = myCombi.SelectedValue;
}

protected override MyDateTime_OnChange(object sender, eventargs e)
{
  if (eventBubbleCombi )
  {
     eventBubbleCombi = false;
     return;
  }

  // process DateStuff here
  // update other control
  eventBubbledDate = true;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an Enumeration to track state instead of using boolean 'flags' but I think bools are easier to demonstrate.

Comment: Looks like the sender is always the control itself, DateTimePicker for DateTimePicker Changed event.

Comment: I will check it out.  It might take a little bit.  Thanks so much for your help!  I will let you know.

Comment: Both answers worked but removing the method from the event used less code.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I would urge a small air of caution, removing the event and re-adding it may cause hard-to-debug race conditions in other seemingly unrelated areas. For example, what if you have a number of events queued up because windows is giving priority to another task, but your event triggers and removes the handler only to have windows take its time away again ... it's a world of hurt trying to debug these things which is why I didn't mention it and why recording state is similar to how windows and .net itself does it internally.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I will take that into account.